# Width of list item isn't adjusting past maximum pixel declaration

Tags: javascript, responsiveness

I have a small script that detects window width and adjusts sub navigation list items if the screen is between `600px` and `1200px`.  The script works within constraints, however when the browser resizes past `1200px` or below `600px`, the width declaration stays applied to each relevant list item.  However, once the page is refreshed the width is what it's supposed to be.  First time poster here so please let me know what I'm missing.

Thanks

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var sub_menu_list_item = $('.current-menu-item .sub-menu li');
var sub_menu_list_item_count = sub_menu_list_item.length;
var divisor = ( 1 / sub_menu_list_item_count );
var width = divisor * 100;
var ww = $(window).width();

if ( ww > 600 && ww < 1200 ){
    if ( sub_menu_list_item_count % sub_menu_list_item_count === 0 ){
        sub_menu_list_item.css('width',  width + '%' );
    } 
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're not applying a `width` style to the sub-items in the "else" case. That is, when the window width is less than `600px` or greater than `1200px`. So those items that are sized while the window is within your `600px` - `1200px` width constraints will remain that way until the page is refreshed.

If you come up with a default case, you can set the `width` style just like you did in your `if` body.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var sub_menu_list_item = $('.current-menu-item .sub-menu li');
    var sub_menu_list_item_count = sub_menu_list_item.length;
    var divisor = ( 1 / sub_menu_list_item_count );
    var width = divisor * 100;
    var ww = $(window).width();

    if ( ww > 600 && ww < 1200 ){
        if ( sub_menu_list_item_count % sub_menu_list_item_count === 0 ){
            sub_menu_list_item.css('width',  width + '%' );
        } 
    } else {
        sub_menu_list_item.css('width',  'auto' );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  I was applying this initially but I had the else clause applied to the inner 'if' statement, not the one that detects the browser width.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Make sure to mark the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the constrain for screen sizes you don't want

```
if ( ww > 600 && ww < 1200 ){
    if ( sub_menu_list_item_count % sub_menu_list_item_count === 0 ){
        sub_menu_list_item.css('width',  width + '%' );
    } 
    else {
        sub_menu_list_item.css('width',  'auto' );
   }
}
```